# Render while pushing a button in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a simple HTML template in a django app:

```
...
{% block analyze %}
    <br>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="run_script">Run Script</button>
    </form>
    {% if results %}
        <br>
        <a href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, {{results}}" download="results.json">download</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
...
```

So when I push the button, the script in views.py should activate:

```
def analysis(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'run_script' in request.POST:
        ...
        # I get the variable finalresults here
        return render(request, 'template.html', {
            'results' : finalresults,
        })
    #in case the button is not pushed, I either want to render to 
    #the template. But without running the script
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

The first time I enter there, it works. I push the button, and it runs my script.
The problem is, when I reload the page, it automatically runs the script, without pushing the button.

I just want the script to be run when I press the button, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when you reload page, browser remember last HTTP method (POST) and you send same request then you send by button.

For resolving this problem you should return redirect to this page instead of render.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page,I guess by clicking the reload button in the browser the request is sent again to the django server,if you try by reloading the URL and not refreshing it by clicking the reload button, it will work fine.
You can use ajax onclick() on the button to trigger a request to django,instead of POST method.This will prevent page reloading.

You can take help of this link https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html